# finding the shortest distance between a point and a set i.e $d(x,A)$

Tags: real-analysis

$X = C[0,1]$ with sup metric.
$A$ is the set of all functions $z\in X$ with $z(0)=0$. $x$ is the function $x(t) = t^2$ ,$y(t)=\cos(2\pi t)$ . Find $d(x,A)$ and $d(y,A)$

Attempt: as $x(t) = t^2$ is continuous and $x(0) = 0$ so $x\in A$ then $d(x,A) = 0$

for $y(t)$ we can see that $\sup |\cos(2\pi t) - z(t)| \leq \sup [t + |z(t)|] = 1 + \sup|z(t)|$ for $t\in [0,1]$, it can get the infimum value $1$ only when $z = 0$.

since $d(y,A) = \inf${ $1 + \sup |z(t)|: z\in A$}
so $d(y,A) = 1$.
Is my reasoning for the last part correct?

I just learned this concept and I want to see if I learned it correctly.

Comment: You need to account for the fact that $y(t)$ is not an element of $A$, since $y(0) \neq 0$

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, lemme try for $y$

Comment: @SamFreedman will it be $1$?

Comment: Yes, but you'll need a proof for why. Expanding the definitions, prove that $\inf_{z \in A} \sup_{t \in [0, 1]} |y(t) - z(t)| = 1$.

Comment: $\sup_{t∈[0,1]}|y(t)−z(t)|=1$ for every $z$ is clear so $\inf (1,1...) = 1$

Comment: Functions in A can take on very large values, making the supremum much larger than 1 in general.

Comment: Oh yes,and if we take $z(t) = 0$ for all $t\in [0,1]$ then $\sup_{t∈[0,1]}|y(t)−z(t)|=1$, so I have to prove that there doesn't exists any function $z\in A$ such that $\sup_{t∈[0,1]}|y(t)−z(t)|<1$

Comment: since $\sup |\cos(2\pi t) - z(t)| < \sup [t + |z(t)|] = 1 + \sup|z(t)|$ for $t\in [0,1]$, it can get the infimum value $1$ only when $z = 0$. will this work? I guess something is missing, help me fill up the gaps @SamFreedman Thanks

Comment: My suggestion is to incorporate your thoughts on this into the question so others can help with your specific subquestions from this approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if $x\in  A$ then, $$\mbox{dist} (x,A)  =0$$ in any metric space.

For any $z \in A $ we have $$||z-y||_{\infty} \geq |x(0)-y(0)|=1$$
hence $$\mbox{dist} (y,A)\geq 1$$ but for the function $A\ni z_0 (t) \equiv 0$ on $[0,1].$ We get $$||z_0-y||_{\infty} =\sup_{t\in [0,1]} |0-\cos (2\pi t )|=1$$ hence $$\mbox{dist} (y,A)  =1$$

Comment: I guess my solution was wrong, can you please elaborate for $y(t)$

Comment: Your solution was correct since $x(0)=y(0)=0$ then $x,y\in A$ so the distance between the point $x $ and a set $A$ is equal to $0$ and its the same as the distance between the point $y $ and a set $A.$

Comment: Careful, $y(0) = \cos(2\pi * 0) = 1$.

Comment: well $y(0)\neq 0$

Comment: Nice! suppose we have a polynomial in $t$ say $w(t)$ then $d(w,A) = k$ where k is the constant term?